# Copying records matching a specific field, to a specific sheet in an Excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm totally new to scripting and have been learning Python. I'm trying to copy an entire row of data from one Excel file to another. More specifically, I have a field called `bound` in my input excel spreadsheet. When this equals `5002`, I'd like to copy that entire row to a sheet called 'bound_5002' in a new spreadsheet created by the Python script. My script works when I hardcode 5002 and `bound_5002`, but I have a list of about 30 of these unique bound codes that I'd like it to cycle through. I've tried to iterate through a list of the codes (shown below), but it creates an Excel file that is incorrect. Upon opening an error message appears

> we found a problem with some content in `data_recon_xlsx`. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can...

It has created new tabs with no data and the names `ecovered_Sheet1` etc. Is my iterator wrong, missing something or can this function not work when iterating through a list?

Written the script without it iterating and it works when hardcoded in, but on trying to iterate through a list of codes it doesn't. I've tried printing out the fields being iterated, adding in a `'` character either side (sheet_ref) or without commas.

Expected - an Excel file called 'data_recon.xlsx' with multiple tabs, containing the data for the corresponding bound field.
Actual - an Excel file with all the tabs created and headers as required, but missing the data that was required to be copied across. New sheets have been added but they are blank and have the names, 'Recovered_Sheet1', 'Recovered_Sheet2', etc.

```
### Create a list of the domain codes of interest

bounds = ['800', '3001', '3002', '3003', '3101', '3102', '3103', '3105', '3106', '3110', '3111', '3112', '5002', '5003', '5004', '5005', '5006', '5101', '5102', '5104', '5105', '5106', '5107', '5110', '9003', '9004', '9101', '9102', '9103', '9104', '9105', '9106']

### Copy out only the matching domains to the tabs
i = 0
ids = [(bounds[i])]
final_result = {}

while i <= 15:

    with open(import_file_path_orig, 'r') as NN:
        reader = csv.reader(NN)
        next(reader)
        for compid, dhid, length, gimp, to, bound, auppm, aucap in reader:
            if bound in ids:
                final_result.setdefault('compid', []).append(compid)
                final_result.setdefault('dhid', []).append(dhid)
                final_result.setdefault('length', []).append(length)
                final_result.setdefault('gimp', []).append(gimp)
                final_result.setdefault('to', []).append(to)
                final_result.setdefault('bound', []).append(bound)
                final_result.setdefault('auppm', []).append(auppm)
                final_result.setdefault('aucap', []).append(aucap)

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_result)

### Paste the data matching the bound from dataframe to Excel sheet

    book = load_workbook('data_recon.xlsx')
    sheet_ref = ("'" + 'bound_'+ bounds[i] + "'")
    sheet_name = (sheet_ref)


    with pd.ExcelWriter('data_recon.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:

        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow = 1, startcol=0, header=False, index=False, engine='openpyxl')

        writer.save()

    print("bound_" + bounds[i] + " Sheet Populated")

    ### tests
    print (sheet_ref)
    print (bounds[i])

    i += 1

print("DATA RECON FILE COMPLETE")
```

Below is showing an earlier version, without it iterating and works as required:

```
### Copy out only the matching domains to the tabs


ids = ['5101']
final_result = {}

with open('inout_file.csv', 'r') as NN:
        reader = csv.reader(NN)
        next(reader)
        for compid, dhid, length, gimp, to, bound, auppm, aucap in reader:
            if bound in ids:
                final_result.setdefault('compid', []).append(compid)
                final_result.setdefault('dhid', []).append(dhid)
                final_result.setdefault('length', []).append(length)
                final_result.setdefault('gimp', []).append(gimp)
                final_result.setdefault('to', []).append(to)
                final_result.setdefault('bound', []).append(bound)
                final_result.setdefault('auppm', []).append(auppm)
                final_result.setdefault('aucap', []).append(aucap)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_result)

### Paste the data matching the bound from dataframe to Excel sheet

book = load_workbook('data_recon.xlsx')
sheet_name = 'bound_5101'


with pd.ExcelWriter('data_recon.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:

    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow = 1, startcol=0, header=False, index=False, engine='openpyxl')

print(sheet_name + " Sheet Populated")
```

Comment: It's just not possible to answer your question without the code, sorry. Please provide a [mcve]. Otherwise, we'd just have to write it from scratch, but it seems you did some of the work already.

Comment: Sorry I was struggling pasting the code in, is there now thanks for looking ^

Comment: The sheet 'data_recon.xlsx' has been created, with all the required sheets and headers, earlier in the script (not shown). The idea here is that the file is opened, and the pandas dataframe data written into the corresponding sheet i.e. 'bound_5002'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've updated this answer to show a much simpler version of what you have outlined above**

In order to write multiple dataframes to a file on different sheets you need to do this outside of your loop once you have all the dataframes built.

```
# Import the csv file into a single datafrome
df = pd.read_csv(import_file_path_orig, columns=['compid', 'dhid', 'length', 'gimp', 'to', 'bound', 'auppm', 'aucap'])

# Creating a new sheet for each dataframe
# Open the proper filehandle
with pd.ExcelWriter('data_recon.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:

# ....   If you have other stuff to do on the main sheet, do it here ....

# Now, we write a single sheet for each set of rows that include the 'bound' value
for b in bounds:
    # Filter the dataset for those rows that match the current value of `b`
    temp_df = df[df['bound']==b]

    # Build the name of the sheet to be written
    sheet_name = f'bound_{b}'

    # Write the filtered values to a sheet in the current workbook
    temp_df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

The issue in your current code is that once you write a workbook, it will be rewritten by the next time you try to write the workbook, you can't add sheets.  [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html?highlight=to_excel#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've just added on an earlier version that works. I've found that it does just add in the data without overwriting everything else. There were a few steps not shown earlier in the script that write the 'data_recon.xlsx' file, add in headers and equations on each tab. The second block of code successfully pulls the data where the bound field is 5101 and adds it to the sheet bound_5101 without wiping out all the stuff I already printed to it.